# lvalue required as left operand of assignment c++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

ERROR:
Lvalue requiered as left operand of assignment (line 4)

Please help me to understand, what i make wrong and why this error happens?

```
int *x = nullptr;
x = (int*) realloc(x, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    (x + i) = new int(i + 3);
}
```

Comment: What is the one variable?

Comment: Sorry, misprint. One supposed to be x

Comment: `x` has type `int*`, so `x+i` also has type `int*`. Type-wise, your code checks out. However, it does not make sense semantically: `x+i` is the address of some `int`, and you are trying to assign a new address (`int*`) to it. The correct syntax is `*(x + i) = i+3` or `x[i] = i+3`

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName That depends on what `x` actually is.

Comment: This is the same situation as `int x = 0; int i = 1; (x + i) = 3;`, which you would not expect to work. (The most important thing to learn about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(x + i) = new int(i + 3);
```

should be

```
*(x + i) = i + 3;
```

---

`(x + i)` will result in a pointer rvalue (`const int*`) which cannot be assigned to, but validly dereferenced `*(x + i)`.

---

In general you should avoid manual memory memory management in c++ code (especially not using `realloc()`).

You would rewrite your code snippet c++ compliant as follows:

```
std::vector<int> x(10);
int i = 0;
for (auto& elem : x) {
    elem = i + 3;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i've got it!

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic here does not yield an lvalue. So you cannot do this:

```
(x + i) = new int(i + 3);
```

What you probably meant was this:

```
*(x + i) = i + 3;
```

Comment: Ok, and why pointer arithmetic doesn't yield lvalue? Just HERE with new()? Or do always pointer arithmetic yield rvalues?

Comment: @Ivan _Pointer arithmetic_ doesn't yield in lvalue pointers, the pointers can dereferenced though to get lvalue references, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Ivan: The result of the pointer arithmetic here is an address. It cannot be assigned to another address. It is like writing: `123 = 456;`